# Can anyone explain me what is the purpose of successful_frame_read in this code?

Tags: python, opencv

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    successful_frame_read, frame = webcam.read()
```

Comment: `cap.read()` returns a bool (True/False). If the frame is read correctly, it will be True. So you can check for the end of the video by checking this returned value. https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Comment: The _purpose_ is to let you know whether the function was successful.  If it's false, then you can skip processing that frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read()` function you are calling is returning a tuple of two objects.  The syntax: `var1, var2 = some_function()` assigns the items of the returned tuple in order to the variables separated by commas.

As aminrd mentioned in his comment, the variable in question, `successful_frame_read` is assigned a boolean value telling you whether or not a frame was actually found and assigned to the second variable, `frame`.  It is useful for checking when you have reached the end of the video being analyzed by the cv2 VideoCapture object.

Comment: Thanks, this reminded me. I had known this but I forgot.